# How to get mapping data in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, asp.net-core, plsql, asp.net-core-2.1

I have two tables in oracle as per below and need mapping data from these two tables from stored procedure or in c# code for .net core. Both will work for me.

First Table contains data which is in key-value form where "Key" is the ID of the Second Table. Value is the actual data required.

First table  :

```
ID                     Data
1           {"f100000":["02/02/2012"],"f100001":["01/04/2013"]}
```

So, "f100000", "f100001"... etc are the keys and ID for Second table

Second table has simple data with ID and Name

```
ID           Name
f100000  Name of the field
f100001  Name of the field2
```

I would expect the result will be as per below:

```
Key                      Value
Name of the field     02/02/2012
Name of the field2    01/04/2013
```

Comment: Which version of oracle are you using?

Comment: Share your attempt code

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to happen in current form without extraneous code which is redundant/inefficient when database design could be improved.

Can the design of table 1 not be improved i.e. have separate fields for f###### values and for the corresponding date.

That way the f###### values can be indexed so that joins will run efficiently between the two tables.

This amendment would need to be made in the code which inserts records into table.

If not, you would have to:

1. Select rows from table1.
2. Split the string into array based on ',' character
3. Split of each of these array values into another 2 dimension array based on ':' character when looping through first array
4. Strip out '[', ']' and '"' characters from date field for it to be parseable
5. As looping through, then SELECT from table_2.id = value from second array[0] value
6. Print out results line by line

As this would need to be done each time code is run, it is very efficient. Much better to redesign table 1 and add in logic to insert as required.